# Difference between Theorems 2.1.4 and 2.1.5 in Tao, Analysis II (2015, 3e)

Tags: real-analysis

To my untrained eye, (a) and (b) in Theorems 2.1.4 and 2.1.5 below seem the same.

What's the difference? What am I missing or why's he repeating himself? From pp. [28-29](https://books.google.com/books?id=oybkDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA28):

> We now generalize much of the discussion in Chapter 9 . We first observe that continuous functions preserve convergence:

> **Theorem 2.1.4** (Continuity preserves convergence). Suppose that $\left(X, d_{X}\right)$ and $\left(Y, d_{Y}\right)$ are metric spaces. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function, and let $x_{0} \in X$ be a point in $X$. Then the following three statements are logically equivalent:
> (a) $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$.
> (b) Whenever $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X$ which converges to $x_{0}$ with respect to the metric $d_{X}$, the sequence $\left(f\left(x^{(n)}\right)\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f\left(x_{0}\right)$ with respect to the metric $d_{Y}$.
> (c) For every open set $V \subset Y$ that contains $f\left(x_{0}\right)$, there exists an open set $U \subset X$ containing $x_{0}$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.
> Proof. See Exercise 2.1.1.
> Another important characterization of continuous functions involves open sets.

> Another important characterization of continuous functions involves open sets.

> **Theorem 2.1.5**. Let $\left(X, d_{X}\right)$ be a metric space, and let $\left(Y, d_{Y}\right)$ be another metric space. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function. Then the following four statements are equivalent:
> (a) $f$ is continuous.
> (b) Whenever $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X$ which converges to some point $x_{0} \in X$ with respect to the metric $d_{X}$, the sequence $\left(f\left(x^{(n)}\right)\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f\left(x_{0}\right)$ with respect to the metric $d_{Y}$.
> (c) Whenever $V$ is an open set in $Y$, the set $f^{-1}(V):=\{x \in X:$ $f(x) \in V\}$ is an open set in $X$.
> (d) Whenever $F$ is a closed set in $Y$, the set $f^{-1}(F):=\{x \in X:$ $f(x) \in F\}$ is a closed set in $X$.
> Proof. See Exercise 2.1.2.

Comment: You should type it out so that the content can be searched.

Comment: The first theorem is about continuity at some point $x_0$. The second theorem is about continuity on the whole domain $X$.

Comment: Th $2.1.4 $ basically told us about local continuity i.e continuous at a point and Th$2.1.5$ defines global continuity.

Comment: O ok got it thanks!